Pre image orientation and smooth map
I consider a smooth map $ F: X\to N$ where $X$ and $N$ are smooth, oriented manifolds of dimension $m+1$ and $m$ respectively, $X$ being compact and with boundary $\partial X=M$.
For a regular value $y\in\partial X$, I consider the manifold $F^{-1}(y)$. and the sub-manifold $A\subset F^{-1}(y)$ with dimension $1$.
I would like to prove that the induced orientation on $A$ is determined by $dF$. That is, if we denote $\pi_y$ the choice of orientation for $TN_y$ we have
$$
v_1\in\pi_{x}\iff (dF_{x}(v_2),…,dF_{x}(v_{n+1}))\in\pi_{y}
$$
Where $\pi_x$ is the choice of orientation for $TA_x$, $v_1$ is a basis of $TA_x$ and $(v_2,…,v_{n+1})$ are such that $(v_1,v_2,…,v_{n+1})$ is a basis of
$TX_x = TA_{x}\oplus (TA_{x})^{\perp}$.
My attempt : Let $x\in A$, we have that $TX_x = TA_{x}\oplus (TA_{x})^{\perp}$. Let consider a basis of the tangent space at $x$ of the form $(v_1,…,v_{n+1})$ with $v_1\in TA_{x}$ and $(v_2,…v_{n+1})\in (TA_{x})^{\perp}$. From the direct product orientation we know that $v_1$ is determined by $(v_2,…v_{n+1})$. Moreover, since $M$ and $N$ have the same dimension, if we consider $F$ as a map from $M$ to $N$ we have that $dF_{x} : TM_{x}\to TN_{y}$.
From there, things get sloppy. I do not see how to make the link with the choice of $v_1$ and $dF_x$. Since $F(x)=y$ and $y$ is a regular value we can use the inverse function theorem to ensures that $dF_x$ is in fact an isomorphism from $TM_x\to TN_y$. Since an orientation has been fixed for $N$, I would like to consider the pullback orientation given by $dF_x$ however I cannot see how to make the bridge between $TM_x$ and $(v_2,…v_{n+1})$ that are vectors in $(TA_{x})^{\perp}$.
I think that, at least for the last part of my attempt, I am not on the right track. If you have some help to provide through a comment or an answer do not hesitate please.
Thank you a lot

$M$ and $N$ are not abstract smooth manifolds but sub-manifolds of the Euclidean space

What do you mean by "linked"?

@AlexPawelko Very sorry for the ambiguity. I updated the post I hope it is clearer now ! Let me know if it is not the case please
